# What does "Stateful" means in Stateful ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, xaml

I was reading about some `XAML` patterns, and there was the Stateful ViewModel, according to what I read it has nothing different than what we as just the "`ViewModel`".

Here's a description for example :

> **Stateful View Model**:
>
> To create isolation between business logic and presentation, data
>   should be removed from the view. The stateful view model pattern moves
>   data into the view model using XAML data binding. This allows the view
>   model to be tested without constructing a view, and it allows the view
>   to change with minimal impact on the business logic.

What is so special about it to be called `Stateful ViewModel` ? why isn't just called `ViewModel`

Link : http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateful-view-model

Answer (score 1):

See the [Stateless view model](http://www.xamlpatterns.com/stateless-view-models), which is the opposite, for more explanation. Basically, in the stateful pattern data is kept on the model whereas in stateless it is not.

Comment: `in the stateful model data is kept on the view` are you sure ?

Comment: Oops, I meant the model. Edited!